# Is it possible to render a partial and force the browser not to load from cache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, partials

I have a window and when it opens, I need to make sure that the image is its latest state.

So I thought why not..

```
render :partial => 'logo', :cache => false
```

but that's not really rails. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not:

```
<img src="youimg.jpg?56734678">
```

The number would be the current time or something like that.

Comment: oh i guess i thought i could do something railsy. last case scenario though, i will probably use the benevolent old lady javascript

Comment: you could set meta cache control to no cache, but that would reload the whole page